# Spring: Error with Bean Aliasing

Tags: java, spring

I got the following exception while Running my Spring Application:

```
Jan 09, 2015 2:47:33 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/amscoder/ba/common/application-context.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'agent' is defined
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1114)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:279)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
      at com.amscoder.ba.test.RobotTest.main(RobotTest.java:15)
```

**My Spring Bean Configuration File is** :"application-context.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
<bean id="robot" class="com.amscoder.ba.beans.Robot">
    <property name="id" value="101" />
    <property name="name" value="Robot-1" />
</bean>

<alias name="agent" alias="robot" />
```

Actually i want to give multiple names to my bean.
Can anyone help me in resolve the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
<alias name="robot" alias="agent" />
```

Note: `agent` is the alias, not `robot`